# when the union of the set of power sets equals the power set of the union of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Herbert B.Enderton,exercise 24, b) it is asked to prove that $ \bigcup \{\mathcal P(X)|X\in A \} \subseteq \mathcal P( \bigcup A) $.  I have proved that but then we are asked  under which conditions the equality holds, that is when
$  \mathcal P( \bigcup A)  \subseteq   \{\mathcal P(X)|X\in A \}   $
So taking  $ x \in \mathcal P( \bigcup A)   \Rightarrow x \subseteq \bigcup A $ I need to get that $x \subseteq  X$ for some $ X \in A $ , So i guess asking $  \bigcup A \subseteq X $   for some $ X \in A $ should be enough. Is this correct?  Can someone give me and example when the equality holds?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you think about it, the only instance when there is some $X\in A$ such that $\bigcup A\subseteq X$ is when $\bigcup A\in A$, isn't it? Because by definition $X\subseteq \bigcup A$ for all $X\in A$.

And in fact this is the condition: $\bigcup\{\mathcal P(X)\,:\, X\in A\}=\mathcal P\left(\bigcup A\right)$ if and only if $\bigcup A\in A$.

$[\Leftarrow]$ is obvious. For $[\Rightarrow]$, notice that $\bigcup A\in\mathcal P\left(\bigcup A\right)$, therefore there must be some $X\in A$ such that $\bigcup A\subseteq X$. But $X\subseteq \bigcup A$ because $X\in A$, therefore $X=\bigcup A$.